# Manifest.json dinamico ? É possivel

Tags: pwa

Oi,

Eu tenho um manifest.json que esta funcionando perfeitamente.
O problema é que eu queria que o start_url dele fosse dinamico e eu pudesse preencher.

Ja vi respostas de 2 anos atras dizendo que nao é possivel e algumas soluções que nao deu certo ( vou colocar abaixo ).

Podem me ajudar com uma mensagem atual ?

```
{
  "name": "Teste",
  "short_name": "teste",
  "theme_color": "#2196f3",
  "background_color": "#2196f3",
  "display": "standalone",
  "Scope": "/m/",
  "start_url": "",
  "icons": [ {
    "src": "../m/public/img/logo_192.png",
    "sizes": "192x192",
    "type": "image/png"
  },{
    "src": "../m/public/img/logo512.png",
    "sizes": "512x512",
    "type": "image/png"
  }]

}
```

Ja tentei fazer uma solução tambem que nao deu certo, criei um arquivo php e inseri .. Ele até funciona, mas o arquivo pwa é gerado como link e nao como app instalavel

O que eu ja tentei

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myDynamicManifest = {

        "name": "Teste",
        "short_name": "teste",
        "theme_color": "#2196f3",
        "background_color": "#2196f3",
        "display": "standalone",
        "Scope": "<?=DIRECTORY_ROOT?><?=$_SESSION['PagName']?>",
        "start_url": "<?=DIRECTORY_ROOT?><?=$_SESSION['PagName']?>",
        "icons": [ {
        "src": "<?=PATH_IMAGE?>logo_192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
    },{
        "src": "<?=PATH_IMAGE?>logo512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
    }]

    };



    const stringManifest = JSON.stringify(myDynamicManifest);
    const blob = new Blob([stringManifest], {type: 'application/json'});
    const manifestURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.querySelector('#manifesto').setAttribute('href', manifestURL);
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw_gdscartao.js').then(function(registration) {
                console.log("Serviceworker Registrado");


            }).catch(function(err) {
                alert('erro' + err);
                // registration failed :(
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
            });
        });
    };




</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui resolver usando o exemplo do site https://medium.com/@alshakero/how-to-setup-your-web-app-manifest-dynamically-using-javascript-f7fbee899a61

```
var myDynamicManifest = {
  "name": "Your Great Site",
  "short_name": "Site",
  "description": "Something dynamic",
  "start_url": "<your-url>",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "theme_color": "#0f4a73",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "whatever.png",
    "sizes": "256x256",
    "type": "image/png"
  }]
}
const stringManifest = JSON.stringify(myDynamicManifest);
const blob = new Blob([stringManifest], {type: 'application/json'});
const manifestURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.querySelector('#my-manifest-placeholder').setAttribute('href', manifestURL);
```

Porém o A2HS( Adicionar a pagina inicial ) mudou o comportamento. Ele começou a adicionar como atalho de site e nao app instalavel

Para resolver , direcionei o start_url para um arquivo php e fiz a tratativa atraves desse arquivo.

Comment: Ola amigo, como fez essa tratativa? estou com esse mesmo problema. Obrigado

Comment: Oi Jonas, tudo bem ... me passa o seu contato, posso te explicar com mais detalhes..  mas praticamente , eu usei um arquivo php, com uma chamada 

<?php
<script type="text/javascript">

Igual ta no segundo exemplo do post inicial.

E depois usei o exemplo do site em questao ...